# How to binding data to xamGrid using linq

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, infragistics

I have an xamGrid of infragastics  but i have no idea binding data using linq.
   The project is a silverlight application. my connected to my WCF data service  based on  VatTu.edmx (ADO.NET Entity Data Model)
   In xamGrid, i create 2 columns with headertext:ID and Name
   In MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace SilverlightApplication12
{
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    private VattuEntities db;
    private DataServiceCollection<VatTu> vts;
    public MainPage()
    {
        db = new VattuEntities(new Uri("http://localhost:43664/VatTuService.svc"));
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var q= from vt in db.VatTus select vt;
        vts.LoadAsync(q);
        grid.itemsource=vts;  
    }       
}}
```

"vt" have 2 properties: ID and name.
   But the page  always load 100% and never show my designed page.
   Please  help me.
   Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do

```
var queryObj = (DataServiceQuery<List<VaTu>>) q;

queryObj .BeginExecute(result=>
{
grid.itemsource=
queryObj .EndExecute(result).ToList();
},
null);
```

Comment: i don't know how or why, but it won't load at all still at 100%. I tried that code.

Comment: i use chrome as my default browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this blog:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/mihail_mateev/archive/2010/06/07/using-the-infragistics-xamgrid-with-ria-services.aspx

which explains step by step how to use Infragistics XamGrid with WCF.